# IE10 does not seem to fire load event

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, load, internet-explorer-10

I expect we're all a bit bored with browser differences, but this one seems a bit serious.
The following almost speaks for itself:

```
$(function() {
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        $('#imgdiv').imagefit();
    }

    $('img').bind('load', function() {
        $('#imgdiv').imagefit();
    });
});
```

In IE10, the load event handler does not seem to fire, but all is well if I place *imagefit()* in the *ready()* function.  On the other hand, if I did this in Chrome, the image will not display at all.  Does anyone have any explanation for this?  My guess is that the two browsers are doing things in a different order, or something.  Just a confirmation that this is a recognised problem would be good.

Comment: why are you checking for the browser in the first place? shouldn't you also be using responsive css?

Comment: Load is deprecated http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 2):

From the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) for the `load` event:

> **Caveats of the `load` event when used with images**
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

The first bullet point addresses your issue I would assume.

I can suggest moving the function call, `$('#imgdiv').imagefit();`, to the bottom of the HTML page. In the case of an external script, deferring the script may help.

Comment: It's been deprecated for a very long time because of these issues. There is no reliable way to do loading in javascript. The language doesn't lend itself to this type of processing.